# I couldn't install Ubuntu with "Something Else" option

Tags: installation, dual-boot, partitioning, windows-7

The option Install Ubuntu alongside Windows 7 is not listed (I have 15GB free space in c drive).

In the "Something Else" option there are 4 drives listed:

- 1MB drive for windows loader
- 100MB drive (Windows)
- 30GB- c drive
- 45GB- else partitions.

Since there are 4 partitions, I cannot install Ubuntu (I cannot delete that 45GB since there are a lot of files in it).

If I shrink the C drive to install Ubuntu, even then I cannot make a partition for Ubuntu since there are 4 partitions.

If I remove that 1MB drive (which shows "Windows loader" next to it) and from the unallocated space I create 2 partitions (swap and ext4) and install Ubuntu, will this idea work??
Please help me to install Ubuntu.

--

[image]

Comment: I don't think there should be 2 partitions for Windows. It's usually just that one 100MB partition. Can you please choose to "Try Ubuntu" when you boot from the USB/CD, then open the program called GParted, take a print screen of it, upload it to http://imgur.com and post the link to the image here?

Comment: take a backup of files inside 1mb partition?What was the filesystem of 1mb partition?did you able to access it from windows or ubuntu live disk?

Comment: I am not sure about the 100MB thing, but I think it is created during the setup and installation of Windows 7.

Comment: The exclamation mark means something is wrong with those partition. It probably means you did not shutdown a clean windows. I would fix that FIRST before messing with partitions.

Comment: first click on the gparted and select the refresh devices option.If the exclamatory mark was still not gone then try the above @Rinzwind comment.

Answer (score 0):

Yes shrunk the `c` drive and delete the 1Mb Partition.From that unallocated space create an extended partition.

Fomat the space inside the extended partition to ext4 filesystem and then install Ubuntu on it.

Comment: Do you know what this 1 MB partition is?

Answer (score 0):

"something else" will only show when there is unallocated space on a partition. Free space on a C drive is still allocated to Windows so you need to create room for a 2nd operating system 1st.

You can use a live gParted CD to create room on the Windows disc but you only have 10Gb spare on that. You probably will need a bit more and Windows needs free space too.

If sda4 is a normal disc I would shrink that to 9+15Gb=24Gb, might also delete the 1Mb partition and leave the remainder (19Gb) unallocated. Than Ubuntu installer will prompt for "something else" and install Ubuntu on that 19Gb.

Comment: before that he had to delete the 1mb partition.

Comment: if sda3 is c: and sda4 is d: deleting the 1 Mb is useless since he wont be able to merge c: with the 1Mb ;)

Comment: without deleting that 1mb partition he cant able to create another one,because it has already 4 partitions.

Answer (score 0):

First delete the 1MB drive (Win loader).
Shrink the c/other drive.
Create 2 logical drives as ext4 and swap.
Install Ubuntu in ext4 drive for dual boot. :)